# String contains substring but entry in wrong way

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
list = ['task','task_notes','task_notice']
```

and I have

```
for elem in list:
   if 'task' in elem:
     #do somth
```

but all the three list elements are entrying on if condition.

How can I do it, to only the first list element entry on condition?

Comment: The code in the question results in a NameError. Please edit the post to include reproducible code so that we may be of help

Comment: What is l at the place of `in l`

Comment: I think you meant `elem` instead of `l`. Then just use `if 'task' in list`. No need for loop

Comment: Yes, sorry guys, it is elem instead of l

Comment: Please don't use builtin `list` as a variable name.  You are looking for a substring with the `in` operator and want `==` instead.  If task names are unique, you could even `break` out of the loop on the first hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_list = ['task','task_notes','task_notice']
for elem in my_list:
   if elem == 'task':
     # do somth
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator looks for substrings. In your case, you want `==` to compare the whole string.

Instead of:

```
if 'task' in elem
```

Use:

```
if 'task' == elem
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if 'task' in elem` checks whether `task` is contained in the `elem`, that is, if there's a sub-match of `task` in the `elem`, it will satisfy the condition and will enter the `if` segment.

As you need to exactly match `task` with the elements, you can check:

```
if list.count('task') == 1:
    // do something
```

OR, traditionally:

```
for elem in list:
    if elem == 'task':
        //do something
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you named your list, list.  List is a built-in keyword in Python, and you are confusing Python.

Change the list name to something like `my_list` and change `if elem == 'task'`

- Carden

Comment: I think that the author was trying to find some pattern in the strings, like as long as a string has `task` the program does something.